# Adding Phone Number to Contact Without Email Address

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to move several phones from spreadsheet to contacts, but several of them does not have an email address. If I use *getContactsByName* it returns an array, which I cannot write into. Perhaps there is a way to use the *getContactbyId* ?

Here's the script I am currently using:

```
function updateContacts() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();  
  for (var i = 0; i < sheet.getLastRow()-1; i++) {
    var contactEmail = sheet.getRange(i+2, 3, 1, 1).getValue();
    var myContact = ContactsApp.getContact(contactEmail);
    var group = ContactsApp.getContactGroup("System Group: My Contacts");    

    if (myContact == null){
      group.addContact(ContactsApp.createContact(sheet.getRange(i+2, 1, 1, 1).getValue(), 
                                sheet.getRange(i+2, 1, 1, 1).getValue(), 
                                sheet.getRange(i+2, 3, 1, 1).getValue()));
      var contact = ContactsApp.getContactsByName(sheet.getRange(i+2, 1, 1, 1).getValue());
      contact[1].setPhone(sheet.getRange(i+2, 2, 1, 1).getValue());
    }}}​
```

The spreadsheet is structured as: name, phone, email

Comment: Zero based. Have you tried 'contact[0]'?

Comment: Tried one, as contact[1]. Will do that too :)

Answer (score 2):

You are using undefined method for adding the phone number. It is `addPhone(label, number)` not `setPhone(number)`

Here is test function I used. Both email and number were added without problems.

```
function myFunction() {
  var contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts();

  contacts.forEach(function(contact, i){
    Logger.log("contacts[" + i + "] =" + contact.getFullName());
  });
  contacts[14].addEmail("test", "delete@me.later");


  var contactsByName = ContactsApp.getContactsByName("Ada");

  contactsByName.forEach(function(contact, i){
    Logger.log("contactsByName[" + i + "] =" + contact.getFullName());
  });
  contactsByName[0].addPhone("test", 123456789);
}
```

Note: When I used `ContactsApp.getContacts();` first 13 contacts in returned array were empty. They are not even displayed in gmail. I'm not sure why. But it might be worthwhile to log the data you are working with.